# Floating Action Button Not working in Lollipop

Tags: android, android-appcompat, floating-action-button

I get this error:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #149: Binary XML file line #149: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

I know there is a duplicate question, but the answers there do not solve my issue.

This is my build.gradle(app)

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 26
defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 26
    versionCode 14
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v13:26.1.0'
implementation "com.android.support:support-fragment:26.1.0"
```

On the other duplicate question, the answer asked to downgrade the sdkVersion to 25. I tried that, but it broke my whole app. I need to add a lot of extra codes here and there, and remove certain features (notification channel for example) to make it compatible with SDK 25.

Is there anyway around this?

My FAB XML Code:

```
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab_addnew"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24px"
    />
```

Edit: Added on full log cat:

```
09-25 16:20:52.250 5637-5637/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main 
Process: com.xxx.xxx, PID: 5637
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.xxx.xxx/com.xxx.xxx.OrderActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #149: Binary XML file line #149: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #149: Binary XML file line #149: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:551)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:429)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:380)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.xxx.xxx.OrderActivity.onCreate(OrderActivity.java:72)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7406) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

Edit: Added the rest of XML file as requested.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#E0E0E0"
    tools:context="com.xxx.xxx.OrderActivity">
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/header"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
        android:background="@color/white"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            style="@style/ThemeOverlay.Logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:contentDescription="@string/icon"
            android:src="@drawable/local_icon"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/header"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/border_margin"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/border_margin"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/border_margin"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/org_ID"
            style="@style/AppTheme.Subheader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:lines="1"
            tools:text="ABCD"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/border_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/half_border_margin"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/header"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/user_ID"
            style="@style/AppTheme.Subsubheader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="35"
            android:lines="1"
            tools:text="abc123@gmail.com"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/border_margin"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/org_ID"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/version"
            style="@style/AppTheme.Subsubsubheader"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="30"
            android:lines="1"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/border_margin"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/user_ID"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_24dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/desc_overflow_button"
            android:onClick="showPopup"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/header"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/header"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/border_margin2"
            />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_ID"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Subheader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:lines="1"
        android:text="@string/store"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/double_border_margin"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recycler_orders"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/storespinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recycler_orders"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/order_ID"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/header"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        >
    </Spinner>
        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_orders"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/ConstraintLayout"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/order_ID"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_orders" />
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_loading"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/recycler_orders"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/recycler_orders"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:visibility="gone" />
    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_addnew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24px"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Edit: Add on styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to provide the whole log of the error?

Comment: Hi @ReneFerrari I've add it on, thanks.

Comment: Post your full layout file.

Comment: @HWong Updating the dependencies to 28.0.0 (latest version) didn't help?

Comment: @GokulNathKP Added on full XML file.

Updating to 28.0.0 didn't help too.

Comment: is your AppTheme an `AppCompat Theme`? If not change it to it ;)

Comment: @ReneFerrari unfortunately, it already is :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue. I found that

```
app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24px"
```

from my XML, the drawable file was in the v24 folder, that's what causing the error.

(stupid me)